# Prolog- get a segment of a list

Tags: prolog

In a list `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]` or `[l,a,d,s,b,f,d,p,n]`, I want the segment between a and f, example
`f([a,b,c,d,e,f,g], X) => X = [b,c,d,e]    f([l,a,d,s,b,f,d,p,n], X) => X = [d,s,b]`, I'm not sure how to realise it, is finding the position of "a" and "f", then get the elements between those positions gonna work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can get somewhere, even to a solution with indexes. This is an example:

```
f(List, Sub):-
   nth1(FirstIndex, List, a),
   nth1(LastIndex, List, f),
   LenSub is LastIndex-FirstIndex-1,
   length(Pre, FirstIndex),
   append(Pre, List2, List),
   length(Sub, LenSub),
   append(Sub, _, List2).
```

Maybe there's even some useful built-in predicate that makes the code shorter.

Still, I would prefer a solution that doesn't perceive lists as arrays - where with the help of an index we can directly access the memory address of its corrseponding element - , but perceives lists as what they are in prolog, structures:

```
f(List, Infix):-
   append(_, [a|List1], List),
   append(Infix, [f|_], List1).
```

This definition is not only shorter, but also more efficient than the above one.

**Bonus**: definition as onliner with use of `append/2`, which is shorter, but slightly less efficient than the previous solution with `append/3`:

```
f(List, Infix):- append([_, [a|Infix], [f|_]], List).
```

Comment: Wow, the way you use append to split up this is amazing